# xml beans: error "date before year -4713"

Tags: java, serialization, xmlbeans

I have next xml

```
                  <b:Recording>
                      <b:startTime>2010-08-03T08:39:31.132625</b:startTime>
                      <b:stopTime>2010-08-03T08:40:50.132625</b:stopTime>
                      <b:timeDiff>PT3M10.867375S</b:timeDiff>
                   </b:Recording>
```

during process of serializetion this xml to the beans (I use xml beans framework ) I receive error `date before year -4713` 
How to fix this error ?
Thanks.

P.S.
type of start and stop times are: xsd:dateTime and for timeDiff is: xsd:duration

Comment: Ummm ... if you already have XML, why are you serializing it?  Do you really mean **de** -serializing?  Also, it would be really useful if you included the complete stack trace for the error.

Comment: Yes, I mean de-serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the dates are in another format than expected by the active locale.